# How do you use the Tiger hash function with GPG?

Tags: hash, pgp

I've searched Google and the GnuPG documentation and I haven't been able to find an answer. Some pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Tiger hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_%28cryptography%29) is not part of the [OpenPGP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) which GnuPG implements. A previous version of that standard ([RFC 2440](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2440)) had reserved an identifier for Tiger, but without actually standardizing it (no OID formally assigned). This was removed during elaboration of the next (current) version of OpenPGP, circa 2003, with [apparent consensus](http://www.mhonarc.org/archive/html/ietf-openpgp/2003-03/msg00007.html), on the basis that having too many options may be detrimental to deployment and interoperability.

Older versions of GnuPG *did* implement the Tiger hash function, outside of the standard (by definition) but this was removed as well; apparently, the most recent version of GnuPG which still supported Tiger was version 1.2.6 (from 2004). So, to answer your question: right now, and for the foreseeable future, you *do not* user Tiger with GnuPG.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for TIGER OID, it's 1.3.6.1.4.1.11591.12.2 . RFC 2440 doesn't specify OID, but [GNU, the owner of 1.3.6.1.4.1.11591 OID, published it on their website](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/OID-Allocations.html). Does it account as being "formally assigned"?

So in essence the format is ready, but software is not.